# ASP.NET RSS feed error in link tag in item node? Issue with Razor in Umbraco RSS Feed

Tags: asp.net, xml, razor, rss, umbraco

Having an issue with creating an rss feed against a blog in umbraco using razor.  The code below works but as soon as I try and add any value into the link tag under the item node I get an xml error, below is the code.

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>@landing.uBlogsyRssTitle</title>
        <description>@landing.uBlogsyRssDescription</description>
        <copyright>@landing.uBlogsyRssCopyright</copyright>
        @*<image>@landing.uBlogsyRssImage</image>*@
        <link>@Request.Url.Host@landing.Url</link>
        <lastBuildDate>@lastPubDate.FormatDateTime("ddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")</lastBuildDate>
        <pubDate>@lastPubDate.FormatDateTime("ddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")</pubDate>
        @foreach (var p in posts)
        {
        <item>
            <title>@p.GetProperty("uBlogsyContentTitle").Value</title>            
            <link></link>
            <author>@p.GetProperty("uBlogsyPostAuthor").Value</author>
            <description>@p.GetProperty("uBlogsyContentBody").Value.StripHtml().Trim()</description>            
            <guid>@p.Url</guid>
            <pubDate>@p.GetProperty("uBlogsyPostDate").Value.FormatDateTime("ddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")</pubDate>
        </item>
        }
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my answer to another post with the same problem solved:

Since MVC4 Razor verifies that what you are trying to write is valid HTML. If you fail to do so, Razor fails.

Your code tried to write incorrect HTML:

If you look at the [documentation of link tag in w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp) you can read the same thing expressed in different ways:

- "The  element is an empty element, it contains attributes only."
- "In HTML the  tag has no end tag."

What this mean is that link is a singleton tag, so you must write this tag as a self-closing tag, like this:

`<link atrib1='value1' attrib2='value2' />`

So you can't do what you was trying to do: use an opening and a closing tag with contents inside.

That's why Razor fails to generate this your `<xml>` doc.

But there is one way you can deceive Razor: don't let it know that you're writing a tag, like so:

`@Html.Raw("<link>")--your link's content--@Html.Raw("</link>")`

Remember that Razor is for writing HTML so writing XML with it can become somewhat tricky.